# Как изменить js скрипт wordpress плагина?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Использую плагин Strong Testimonial, нужно немного изменить функционал js скрипта, как это правильно сделать, что бы и после обновления плагина все работало?

Answer (score 0):

Надо смотреть, как скрипт запускается - искать `wp_enqueue_script()`, `wp_register_script()`, `wp_localize_script()` с именем нужного файла. В вашем плагине или вашей дочерней теме отменять запуск скрипта плагина с помощью `wp_dequeue_script()` в функции обработки события `wp_enqueue_scripts` с приоритетом ниже (позже), чем скрипт запускается в Strong Testimonial. Обычно используется приоритет по умолчанию 10, так что ваша функция отмены должна иметь приоритет 20.

Копию скрипта надо поместить в папку/подпапку вашего плагина или вашей дочерней темы. Отредактировать его там.

Запускать ваш скрипт нужно в той же вашей функции с приоритетом 20, после отмены запуска скрипта плагина.

Answer (score -1):

поменяйте версию плагина . например

```
/*
 * Meta Slider. Slideshow plugin for WordPress.
 *
 * Plugin Name: Meta Slider
 * Plugin URI:  https://www.metaslider.com
 * Description: Easy to use slideshow plugin. Create SEO optimised responsive slideshows with Nivo Slider, Flex Slider, Coin Slider and Responsive Slides.
 * Version:     3.5.1
 * Author:      Team Updraft
 * Author URI:  https://www.metaslider.com
 * License:     GPL-2.0+
 * Copyright:   2017 Simba Hosting Ltd
 *
 * Text Domain: ml-slider
 * Domain Path: /languages
 */
```

измените версию на  9.9.9

Comment: плагин не будет обновляться если у него будет измененная версия